# Error compiling content project

Tags: c#, xna, compiler-errors

Having a bit of a problem trying to compile the Content project for XNA,

Basically if there is nothing in the content project, I can compile and run fine, however when I add any type of object (Image, SpriteFont, Texture, Model), it wont compile and always gives this error:

```
Error   1   Building content threw InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Interop.RefDevice' to type 'System.IDisposable'.
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.CommonHelperFunctions.InitD3D()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.TextureImporter.InitD3D()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.TextureImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentImporter`1.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.ImportAssetDirectly(BuildItem item, String importerName)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.ImportAsset(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAssetWorker(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAsset(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.RunTheBuild()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Tasks.BuildContent.RemoteProxy.RunTheBuild(BuildCoordinatorSettings settings, TimestampCache timestampCache, ITaskItem[] sourceAssets, String[]& outputContent, String[]& rebuiltContent, String[]& intermediates, Dictionary`2& dependencyTimestamps, KeyValuePair`2[]& warnings)   D:\Directory\Content\System\UI\Backgrounds\bg.png   SolarFusion
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Does your computer have a video card that supports XNA?

Comment: Like I said, my XNA app runs fine as long as there is no content, the problem is with compilation stage not running.

Comment: This is a very strange error.  I would recommend re-installing XNA and possibly DirectX as a whole.

Comment: Reinstalling didn't seem to work.

Comment: Also reinstalling DirectX on Windows 8, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Completely removing any trace of XNA, and rebooting, then trying to install a fresh copy of XNA Game Studio fixed this for me.